# Gradle 1.8 erroneously reports a task is UP-TO-DATE

Tags: javascript, gradle

This is a quite common scenario, when two flavors of 3rd party JavaScript dependencies are required for a project. For development purposes a non-minified versions of JavaScript files are used, while deploy scenario typically only includes the minified versions (*.min.js).
Let's assume both (minified and non-minified) versions of all the dependencies are in the 'repo' folder. Further, there's 2 versions of the 'main' file, one uses the minified deps 'main.min.js' and while 'main.js' uses the non-minified ones. Let's assume both 'main' files can be generated by some means from the 'deps.json' where all the dependencies are declared. The file structure is as follows:

```
public/
    lib/
repo/
        angular/
            ...
        angular-resource/
            ...
        angular-route/
            ...
build.gradle
deps.json
main.js
main.min.js
```

The `public` folder is where all the output files should appear, so I wrote the corresponding `build.gradle` file:

```
task createMain {
    inputs.file 'deps.json'
    // TODO: read deps.json and create  main.min.js and './main.js
    outputs.file 'main.min.js'
    outputs.file 'main.js'
}

task copyMain(type: Copy, dependsOn: createMain) {
    from('.') {
        include 'main.js'
    }
    into('public')
}

task copyMainForDeploy(type: Copy, dependsOn: createMain) {
    from('.') {
        include 'main.min.js'
    }
    rename('main.min.js','main.js')
    into('public')
}

task installJSDeps(type: Copy, dependsOn: copyMain){
    from('repo')
    into('public/lib')
    outputs.dir 'public/lib'
    inputs.file 'deps.json'
}

task installJSDepsForDeploy(type: Copy, dependsOn: copyMainForDeploy){
    from('repo'){
        include '**/*.min.js'
    }
    into('public/lib')
    outputs.dir 'public/lib'
    inputs.file 'deps.json'


    doFirst {
        //clean up any existing files before copying new ones
        FileTree tree = fileTree (dir: "public/lib");  
        delete(tree)
    }
}
```

What I was hoping to achieve is: if I call `installJSDepsForDeploy` only the minified files appear in `public/lib`, if I call `installJSDeps` all the files appear in `public/lib` (in addition to `main` file being copied/renamed).
What happens is the following:

```
$ gradle installJSDepsForDeploy
:createMain UP-TO-DATE
:copyMainForDeploy
:installJSDepsForDeploy

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.698 secs

$ gradle installJSDeps
:createMain UP-TO-DATE
:copyMain
:installJSDeps

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.484 secs

$ gradle installJSDepsForDeploy
:createMain UP-TO-DATE
:copyMainForDeploy
:installJSDepsForDeploy UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.41 secs
```

The second time `:installJSDepsForDeploy UP-TO-DATE` is reported, which is not desired and as far as I understand, incorrect.

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance,
  Sash

EDIT:

Taking into account the comments bellow, a *more* correct `build.gradle` file would be:

```
task createMain {
    inputs.file 'deps.json'
    // ASSUME: read deps.json and create  main.min.js and './main.js
    outputs.file 'main.min.js'
    outputs.file 'main.js'
}

task copyMain(type: Copy, dependsOn: createMain) {
    from('.') {
        include 'main.js'
    }
    into('public')
}

task copyMainForDeploy(type: Copy, dependsOn: createMain) {
    from('.') {
        include 'main.min.js'
    }
    rename('main.min.js','main.js')
    into('public')
}

task fetchJSDeps {
    // ASSUME: reads `deps.json` and fetches
    // all the deps into `repo` folder
    outputs.dir 'repo'
    inputs.file 'deps.json'        
}

task installJSDeps(type: Copy, dependsOn: ['copyMain','fetchJSDeps']){
    from('repo')
    into('public/lib')
    outputs.dir 'public/lib'
    inputs.file 'deps.json'
}

task installJSDepsForDeploy(type: Copy, dependsOn: ['copyMainForDeploy','fetchJSDeps']){
    from('repo'){
        include '**/*.min.js'
    }
    into('public/lib')
    outputs.dir 'public/lib'
    inputs.file 'deps.json'


    doFirst {
        //clean up any existing files before copying new ones
        FileTree tree = fileTree (dir: "public/lib");  
        delete(tree)
    }
}
```

The corresponding output is still:

```
$ gradle installJSDepsForDeploy
:createMain UP-TO-DATE
:copyMainForDeploy
:fetchJSDeps UP-TO-DATE
:installJSDepsForDeploy

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.769 secs

$ gradle installJSDeps
:createMain UP-TO-DATE
:copyMain
:fetchJSDeps UP-TO-DATE
:installJSDeps

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.519 secs

$ gradle installJSDepsForDeploy
:createMain UP-TO-DATE
:copyMainForDeploy
:fetchJSDeps UP-TO-DATE
:installJSDepsForDeploy UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.376 secs
```

UPDATE:

I've tried a lot of different set-ups and it seems to me that Gradle does not support this kind of tasks. Essentially, I want `taskA` copy from:

```
/repo/**/*.js
/repo/**/*min.js
/repo/**/*min.js.map
/repo/**/*.css
/repo/**/*.md
```

to:

```
/public/lib/**/*min.js
/public/lib/**/*min.js.map
```

And I want `taskB` copy from:

```
/repo/**/*.js
/repo/**/*min.js
/repo/**/*min.js.map
/repo/**/*css
/repo/**/*.md
```

to:

```
/public/lib/**/*.js
/public/lib/**/*.css
/public/lib/**/*.md
```

The tasks *DO NOT* depend on each other, that's in fact the main point here. Further, I want `TaskA` *NOT* to copy the files that `TaskB` is copying. Both tasks need to make sure the files that the other task is copying over *ARE NOT* present after completion.

Basically, after running `gradle taskA` the `public/lib` should include *ONLY*:

```
/public/lib/**/*min.js
/public/lib/**/*min.js.map
```

and *NOT*:

```
/public/lib/**/*.js
/public/lib/**/*.css
/public/lib/**/*.md
```

After running `gradle taskB' the result should be the opposite.
Is it possible to do that in Gradle?

Thanks in advance,
 Sash

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it's not clear to me what you are trying to do here. A minimal example would help.

Some general hints (I couldn't make this a comment because it's too long):

- `createMain` does nothing, which means that the `copyMain` tasks won't have anything to copy (unless you manually put `main.js` and `main.min.js` files in place for now).
- `copyMain` and `copyMainForDeploy` create the same file in the same place, which means that they'll keep overwriting each other's outputs, making the other task out-of-date.
- The task dependencies don't make sense because (say) `installJSDeps` doesn't consume anything that `copyMain` produces (i.e. there is no semantic dependency between the two tasks).
- I don't understand why `deps.json` would be an input to the `Copy` tasks. Also, task types such as `Copy` automatically declare their inputs and outputs based on how they are configured (e.g. `from` and `into`), which means that they don't have to be declared in the build script.
- Instead of `from('.') { include 'foo' }`, `from 'foo'` should be used.
- Instead of deleting the target dir's contents before copying, a `Sync` task should be used (which is configured in exactly the same way as `Copy`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `createMain` does nothing for the purpose of this demo, let's assume it does what it says in the comment: creates the 2 main.js files, which are already present.
You are correct: two tasks create the same file in the same place. But to be exact: the `installJSDeps` creates *more* files than `installJSDepsForDeploy`, the files generated by both are `*.min.js`.
Further, I agree with you: I'd expect they'd be making each other out-of-date and that was intended, but that's exactly what *doesn't happen* and that's the problem.

Comment: `installJSDeps` and `installJSDepsForDeploy` don't make each other out-of-date; in fact, the former will make the latter *up-to-date*. Maybe what you are looking for is to sync the files with `Sync` tasks, rather then copying them with `Copy` tasks. This will delete any files in the target directory that weren't copied over.

Comment: i wasn't aware the `Copy` task automatically declares `inputs` and `outputs`, and frankly I haven't noticed reading the task documentation (might have missed it). Are there many other tasks that do the same? (quick google search doesn't help much). The `Sync` task sounds like what i need, will give it a go.

Comment: The best place to learn about the available task types is the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).